# Data can't be load to Widget after get from Firestorage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and try to create a fitness app that let you add your own workout.
Everything is good so far, until today. I try to loaded a list from Firestore and use FutureBuilder to get the snapshot. It has successfully got the list. But once the UI is fully loaded I got
[smth like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZtkA.png)

Through `snapshot.connectionState` is `ConnectionState.done`, it always return widget from default case. At first, i thought that just because state has not been change so the widget. But it did not help, the button i put there to trigger `setState()` did trigger it, but after `CircularProgressIndicator()` was call, it back to that button once more.

Now i'm really confuse, what i did wrong?

Here my code:

```
class _MyExercisesListState extends State<MyExercisesList> {
  final MyWorkoutData workout;

  _MyExercisesListState(this.workout);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirestoreDatabaseService(
                uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .getWorkout(workout.title),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Lỗi kết nối",
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            List<MyExerciseData> exercises = [];
            FirestoreDatabaseService(
                    uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .getExerciseList(snapshot.data.docs[0]['id'].toString())
                .then(
              (element) async {
                QuerySnapshot snapshot = element;
                snapshot.docs.forEach(
                  (ele) {
                    List<String> list = ele.get('steps').cast<String>();
                    MyExerciseData data = MyExerciseData(
                        description: ele.get('description').toString(),
                        minutes: ele.get('minutes'),
                        progress: ele.get('progress'),
                        steps: list,
                        title: ele.get('title').toString(),
                        video: ele.get('video').toString());
                    exercises.add(data);
                  },
                );
                return ListView.separated(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  itemCount: exercises.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return MyExerciseCell(
                      exercise: exercises[index],
                      workout: workout,
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return const SizedBox(height: 15);
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {}), child: Text(snapshot.connectionState.toString())),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks !
(Sorry for my bad English or bad described)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to create a class member for Future function. Otherwise your Future called every build.

Second, you can merge your Future functions and don't call setState and don't use async function in `FutureBuilder.builder`.

Currently, after the workouts arrive, the widget is already built before the `exercises` filled. Get all the information you need (wait), then build the widget.

Do:

The `future` here should contain the final data when arrive.

```
class _MyExercisesListState extends State<MyExercisesList> {
  
  late Future future;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    future =
        FirestoreDatabaseService(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .getWorkout(workout.title).then((value)  async {
                // fetch new data and return.
             });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      builder: (c,s){
        //...
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this really help!! I finally can done it!! Please accept my gratitude

Comment: Thank, if you mark answer to accepted, Those who come later see what the correct answer is.